# Working with an event handler - but not always.. (How do i...)

Tags: c#, network-programming

I'm quite new to C# and certainly OOP concepts.. so forgive the stupidity of my question.

I have a system I wish to communicate with, It has a number of commands that can be called with an associated response. (Communication is done via TCP/IP or Serial) (I implemented an Interface with SendMessage so that I can use multiple transport mechanisms)

I want to create a method for each command and then expose these, which is simple enough. The device also lets say 'broadcasts' messages as well which I want to act on, so I was using an event handler for this which works well..

At the moment in the event handler I catch OK and ERROR style messages, but ideally I would like to also be able to send the command from the above method and catch an error and return a bool value based on the command.

Can anyone think of a way I can do something like this and point me in the right direction?

Thanks

David

Comment: Too broad, can you show what you are doing currently and what you want instead? Inside method you can subscribe to event, block execution until timeout or event handler is called and then continue if that is the question.

Comment: I guess I want to be able to block the current event handler from doing anything - ie. remove it, and then catch the response within the method just for getting that commands response, and then enable it again, but it doesn't feel correct

Comment: Then don't use event handler. Provide another signaling mechanics (e.g. `Monitor.Pulse` / `Monitor.Wait`). In past I wrote helper for communication class which was subscribing to event, waiting for specific reply and then return. But then I discover `Monitor` existence (thanks to [Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Signaling_with_Wait_and_Pulse)) and using it since then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use helper to wait for event. Some ugly code from past:

```
public class ComWait
{       
    ManualResetEvent _waitEvent;
    SomeEvent _eventHandler;

    public ComWait()
    {
        _waitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        _eventHandler = new SomeEvent(Watch);
    }

    void Watch()
    {
        _waitEvent.Set();
    }

    public bool Wait(int time = 3000) 
    {
        _waitEvent.Reset();
        SomeEvent += _eventHandler;
        bool result = _waitEvent.WaitOne(time, false);
        SomeEvent -= _eventHandler;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage is

```
ComWait wait = new ComWait();
if(!wait.Wait())
    return; // timeout
// process
```

It will simply block synchronous method until event is rised or timeout occurs. It should be easy to add parameters: to unblock on specific event and to pass event handler parameters back to caller.

---

Otherwise I would simply have method inside communication class to use as a blocker:

```
readonly object _waitLock = new object();

public void Wait()
{
    lock (_waitLock)
        if (!Monitor.Wait(_waitLock, 3000))
          throw new TimeoutException("No communications");
}
```

Signal at same time as you rise event:

```
lock (_waitLock)
    Monitor.PulseAll(_waitLock);
```